# Smartphone to smartphone to sim communication

Tags: connection-issues, networking, mobile-network, data-connection

I have purchased a second Android smartphone because the internal memory on my first smartphone was full and I needed to use more space for apps, pictures, and videos. But the second smartphone has no installed sim card (I currently have no need for two sim cards to be used within the same country).

So my question is, provided both phones are on at the same time, and provided no Wi-Fi is available because I happen to be on the road and not at home, what is the best way to have the simless phone utilize the other phone's network operator data network? What network protocol should I use for this and what are the steps involved?

Assume the phone with the sin card is an Android KitKat 4.4.2 and the other a Lollipop 5.1. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the Android versions, or devices themselves, are largely are not relevant to the answer.

The second phone cannot use the first phone's mobile data directly, it must use it via tethering. Activate the mobile/portable hotspot on the first phone and use the WiFi on the second phone to connect to it just like any other WiFi network.

The preferred method would be transfer all data to the second phone (call logs, SMS messages, pictures, etc), then place the SIM in the second phone and use it as your only device and replace the first phone.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason I cannot do this with a single phone is I have too many apps and I cannot find a phone with an internal memory large enough to meet my needs. Perhaps you can suggest one.

Comment: @JackMaddington Shopping suggestions and product recommendation is beyond the scope of this site. But there are phones available with 32 and 64 GB internal storage, and in Marshmallow the SD card can be adopted as internal storage

Comment: That's great! So no longer having to use the SD card for music pictures and video only for fear off apps not working!

Comment: @JackMaddington Sounds like someone needs to do some Googling.  :)